# Why are spaces ignored in natsort / strnatcmp / strnatcasecmp?

Tags: php, natural-sort, natsort

I'm using `strnatcmp` in my comparison function for sorting person names in a table. For our Belgian client, we get some strange results. They have names like 'Van der Broecke' and 'Vander Veere', and `strnatcasecmp("Van der", "Vander")` returns `0`!

As natural comparison aims to sort as a human would, I don't understand why the spaces are completely disregarded.

E.g.:

```
$names = array("Van de broecke", "Vander Veere", "Vande Muizen", "Vander Zoeker", "Van der Programma", "vande Huizen", "vande Kluizen", "vander Muizen", "Van der Luizen");
natcasesort($names);

print_r($names);
```

Gives:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Van de broecke 
[5] => vande Huizen 
[6] => vande Kluizen 
[2] => Vande Muizen 
[8] => Van der Luizen 
[7] => vander Muizen 
[4] => Van der Programma 
[1] => Vander Veere 
[3] => Vander Zoeker 
)
```

But a human would say:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Van de broecke 
[4] => Van der Programma 
[8] => Van der Luizen 
[5] => vande Huizen 
[6] => vande Kluizen 
[2] => Vande Muizen 
[7] => vander Muizen 
[1] => Vander Veere 
[3] => Vander Zoeker 
)
```

My solution now is to replace all spaces with underscores, which are handled properly. Two questions:
Why does `natsort` work like this?
Is there a better solution?

Comment: As I understand, `natsort` sorts strings by numbers as humans do, it doesn't sort correctly if there's no numbers

Comment: @Baldrs No. PHP.net: "This function implements a sort algorithm that orders alphanumeric strings in the way a human being would while maintaining key/value associations. "

Comment: A key phrase is **alphanumeric strings**.

Comment: @Baldrs Exactly. That's the key phrase. "Van der broecke" is an alphanumeric string. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphanumeric

Comment: @Baldrs Note that _ or + are sorted. However spaces are ignored. So the alphanumeric here is not strict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the source code you can actually see this, which definitely seems like a bug:
http://gcov.php.net/PHP_5_3/lcov_html/ext/standard/strnatcmp.c.gcov.php (scroll down to line 130):

```
 //inside a while loop...

 /* Skip consecutive whitespace */
 while (isspace((int)(unsigned char)ca)) {
         ca = *++ap;
 }

 while (isspace((int)(unsigned char)cb)) {
         cb = *++bp;
 }
```

Note that's a link to 5.3, but the same code still exists in 5.5 (http://gcov.php.net/PHP_5_5/lcov_html/ext/standard/strnatcmp.c.gcov.php)
Admittedly my knowledge of C is limited, but this basically appears to be advancing the pointer on each string if the current character is a space, essentially ignoring that character in the sort. The comment implies that it's only doing this if the whitespaces are *consecutive*; however, there is no check to ensure the previous character was actually a space first. That would need something like

```
//declare these outside the loop
short prevAIsSpace = 0;
short prevBIsSpace = 0;

//....in the loop
while (prevAIsSpace && isspace((int)(unsigned char)ca)) {
    //won't get here the first time since prevAIsSpace == 0
    ca = *++ap;
}
//now if the character is a space, flag it for the next iteration
prevAIsSpace = isspace((int)(unsigned char)ca));
//repeat with string b
while (prevBIsSpace && isspace((int)(unsigned char)cb)) {
    cb = *++bp;
}
prevBIsSpace = isspace((int)(unsigned char)cb));
```

Someone who actually knows C could probably write this better, but that's the general idea.

On another potentially interesting note, for your example, if you're using PHP >= 5.4, this gives the same result as the usort mentioned by Aaron Saray (it does lose the key/value associations as well):

```
sort($names, SORT_FLAG_CASE | SORT_STRING);

print_r($names);
Array ( 
    [0] => Van de broecke 
    [1] => Van der Luizen 
    [2] => Van der Programma 
    [3] => vande Huizen 
    [4] => vande Kluizen 
    [5] => Vande Muizen 
    [6] => vander Muizen 
    [7] => Vander Veere 
    [8] => Vander Zoeker
)
```

Comment: Very interesting! Sorry for disregarding this question for a while - I was out of the loop for a bit.

Comment: Thanks - if this is what you were looking for would you mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at bugs.php.net #26412 (natsort() was compressing multiple spaces to 1 space). Apparently, this behavior is so "aa", "a a", and "a  a" (note the 2 spaces) do not sort as identical strings.

Comment: An unaccepted bug report from 2003! :) But it is, in fact, the same core problem..
But I don't understand your conclusion of why this would be. They seem to do the opposite to me: sort aa, a a and a  a as identical, the latter two being absolutely identical, and the former being closer to a a than to ab. It's even more Kolmogorovian complex to add a space and a character... 

I'm still puzzled

Answer (score 2):

Like other answers/commentors have said, this is a known issue.  However, you can write your own sort with usort().  Please try this and see if it works:

```
usort($names2, function($first, $second) {
    if ($first == $second) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return (strtolower($first) < strtolower($second)) ? -1 : 1;
}
});
```

I noticed the output is slightly different than your suggested answer:

You suggested:

```
[4] => Van der Programma 
[8] => Van der Luizen
```

But I'm sure this was a typo - these should be swapped. :)